# Keep element a set distance from top of browser screen without using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstraps modals and so adding `position:fixed` doesnt work.

I have an arrow element pointing towards the modal triggering element. I want this arrow to point to the trigger wherever that trigger is on the screen.

I can do this easily enough with:

```
$("[data-toggle='modal']").click(function() {
    triggerpos = $(this).offset().top;
    $('.modal-arrow').css('top', triggerpos + "px");
});
```

The problem is that if there is a long modal that causes the user to scroll, then the arrow doesn't stay fixed; it moves with the modal as the user scrolls.

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umv4jhLg/22/

Of course I have tried various arrangements with CSS, but with no result.

I have also tried adjusting it on window scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var triggerpos = $(this).offset().top;
    $('.modal-arrow').css('top', triggerpos + "px");  
})
```

but with no results.

Would anyone know of a way that I can keep the `.modal-arrow` steady using Jquery?

Comment: By using jquery, **you're essentially using CSS**. I would just put a random div there, so the other one can "stand" on it

Answer (score 0):

try it with [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

add that to your top position